# Can't Install firefox in OpenBSD/sparc64

Tags: firefox, openbsd, browser, sparc

I just installed OpenBSD on a sparc64 based pc but when I try to do `pkg_add -v firefox` it says `can't find firefox`. I also tried installing `nano`, which installed fine, so why can't it find firefox.

Comment: I haven't used OpenBSD in a while, but try `pkg_add -v mozilla-firefox`. I think you need to specify that it's mozilla-firefox? That's how it used to be, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Tried it but still doesn't work by typing mozilla-firefox.

Comment: Huh. That's changed, so I decided to use a search engine. It used to just install with mozilla-firefox, but now there's a giant thread about it [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/installing-firefox.61998/). How bizarre?

Answer (score 6):

The Firefox browser is available in the `firefox` or `firefox-esr` packages.

Unfortunately for you, neither of these can be built on the `sparc64` architecture (they are for `amd64`, `i386`, and  `aarch64` only).

The port was [marked "broken"](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/www/mozilla-firefox/Makefile?rev=1.275&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) for `sparc64` in 2015:

> Face reality, mark as BROKEN-sparc64. xpcshell SIGBUSes during fake, and
> nobody cares. No point in wasting hours during bulk builds....
> If you want a graphical browser on sparc64, try netsurf.

The `sparc64` build support for the browser was [removed in 2016](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/www/mozilla-firefox/Makefile?rev=1.303&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) with the comment

> Remove the build goo for macppc|sparc64|alpha, it's unlikely
> this will ever come back...

The port was finally [restricted](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/www/mozilla-firefox/Makefile?rev=1.325&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) to a small set of architectures in 2017:

> Set ONLY_FOR_ARCHS properly - all the world is x86 anyway.
> Ditch --disable-debug-symbols on i386, it links fine without it.

An alternative web browser to try may be

- [`dillo` ("fast and light graphical web browser")](https://www.dillo.org/),
- [`midori` ("lightweight web browser")](https://astian.org/en/midori-browser/), or
- [`netsurf` ("lightweight web browser, with GTK interface")](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/).

All three of these are available as pre-built packages for the `sparc64` architecture.